# Filter custom taxonomy posts via AJAX

Tags: categories, customization, ajax, taxonomy

I have been trying to create dynamic sorting of posts on the blog on click on some icons. Posts are custom post type and the have custom taxonomy.

**The objective is:**
On click on category name (of custom taxonomy) show (append) posts of that category below.

**The problem is:**
WP_Query does not accept the arguments.
The result of success function are WP_Query arguments, not html objects or anything usable on the js side.

**The flow:**
I registered and localized the script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-pagination',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/ajax-pagination.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );



wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
                'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
 ));
```

On the server side I do:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_pagination', 'my_ajax_pagination' );

function my_ajax_pagination() {
    $name = $_POST['termname']; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myposttype',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomyname',
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms' =>  $name 
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $posts;


    if( ! $posts->have_posts() ) { 
        echo "I don't work yet";
    }
    else {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
            $posts->the_post();
            $text = apply_filters('the_excerpt', 
            get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));
            echo $text;
        }
    }


    die();
}
```

In the ajax file I go with:

```
(function($) {


    function get_the_category(element){
        return element.context.id;
    };

    $(document).on( 'click', '.cat-icons a', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var termname = get_the_category( $(this).clone() );

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_pagination',
                termname: termname
            },
            success: function( html ) {
                console.log(html);
                //here will do stuf
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Yes, I tried to look that up, no I haven't found the answer and I would like to know what am I doing wrong. I'm new to AJAX and custom post types.

**Questions:**
1. How to achieve the objective with this approach?
2. Is the approach correct & safe?
3. How does that even happen I get `$args` back?
4. I tried to achieve the same with `query_vars` but failed. I couldn't get `tax_query` attached to the `query_vars`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would see `WP_Query` arguments in the data returned, a copy/paste of your code here (with a few adjustments- post type, taxonomy, and term name) does not produce that result.

Getting the post excerpt via `get_post_field` will only work if you explicitly entered an excerpt in that field, it will not generate one from `post_content`. You've also not defined `$post_id`, but that shouldn't matter as it will fall back to the current `$post`.

Here's a version with the unnecessary bits removed, and some slight adjustments:

```
function my_ajax_pagination() {
    $name = $_POST['termname']; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myposttype',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomyname',
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms' =>  $name 
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( ! $posts->have_posts() ) { 
        echo "I don't work yet";
    }
    else {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
            $posts->the_post();
            echo get_the_excerpt();
        }
    }

    die();
}
```

One other change I would suggest is to put your post data into an array and return it via [`wp_send_json`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) rather than echo data and markup directly.

Comment: Thank you! I actually messed up the structure in the real code and I noticed after I edited it for this question upload. I looked into wp_send_json as you suggested to improve it and it works well. Thanks a lot.